# How to extract a portion of a file in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a log file and i have to parse them.
i want to extract a portion of this log file means that 
between two regular expression anything comes would be able to capture .
Like

```
reg="(COPY\s+role\s+\(id\,\s+name\,\s+access\_level.*)"
```

and

```
regex="END"
```

all lines that comes between these two regular expression should able to capture.
For this  i have tried

```
echo "Enter the file to extract"
read file

reg="(COPY\s+role\s+\(id\,\s+name\,\s+access\_level.*)"
regex="END"

if [[ $file =~ $reg ]];then
 while read LINE

 echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
if[[ $LINE =~ $regex ]];then
break;
fi
 done < $file
```

but i am not able to capture anything .Please suggest what to do 
.If i am making it more complicated than suggest me how to do this.

Comment: escape all the backslashes one more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your if should be inside your while, if you want to check every line.

```
state=outside
while read line; do
  if [[ $state = outside ]] && [[ $line =~ $begin_regex ]]; then
    state=inside
  fi
  if [[ $state = inside ]]; then
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    if [[ $line =~ $end_regex ]]; then
      state=outside
      # or break if you only want to do this once
    fi
  fi
done < "$file"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.You are genius

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the before look up and after look up:

before lookup is ?<=
after lookup is ?=

If you replace the below "before_pattern" with your regex before and the "after_pattern" with your regex after, this should capture everything in between.

```
pattern = before_pattern everything in between after_pattern
regex = (?<=before_pattern)(.*)(?=after_pattern)
result = " everything in between "
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: would it able to capture multi line???? .and if file size is very long than it will has huge time complexity

Comment: Add [\s\S] to allow multiline:
e.g. (?<=before_pattern)(.*)[\s\S](?=after_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
 seq 100 | sed -n '/70/,/80/p'
```

This print everything between the first matched line and the second matched line inclusive (more than once if multiple matched segments exist). `70` and `80` are actually regular expressions, for example, you could write

```
eq 100 | sed -rn '/^7./,/^8/p'
```